# How to save logs in robot framework like log.html ,report.html,output.xml with some particular name for ex log.html-> logxyz.html, abcreport.html?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to save the logs with the particular name in robot framework but not able to do that . Do we have a way to save the log name with the name as we want? If yes then how to do that ?

Comment: [Robot framework user's guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#created-outputs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options to configure your output files:

> ```
> -d, --outputdir <dir> Defines where to create output files.
> -o, --output <file>   Sets the path to the generated output file.
> -l, --log <file       Sets the path to the generated log file.
> -r, --report <file>   Sets the path to the generated report file.
> ```

So to change the name of the log file launch your tests like this:

```
robot --log logxyz --report abcreport my_robot.robot
```

You can check all [command line options](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#all-command-line-options) in Robot Framework User Guide to learn more.

With `-T`, `--timestampoutputs` you can add a timestamp to the name of the output files as well. An example name with `--log` and `--timestampoutputs`: `my_log_file_name-20190103-102712.html`.

Comment: Thanks @Benuce Kaulics . It really helped